# What does centertap transformer mean 26.4V 10A

Tags: charger

I'm searching for a transformer for my battery charger unit EBL 264-3. Because the manufacturer SCHAUDT doesnt want to provide the informations regarding the elements in their units I have contacted a guy that repairs the units. He said that the transformer has 26.4V 10A on the secondary coil (centertap). Does this mean 13.2V - 0 - 13.2V ?

[image]

26.4V is a little bit off if I look at the schematics
[image]

Thank you

This is the charger EBL 264-3
[image]

Comment: What’s the output voltage of the entire contraption? Is the transformer damaged?

Comment: What's the problem?  yes 13.2Vac (rms not pk)  at rated VA with 1.4V drop on diode bridge. Convert rms to average??

Comment: This is the motorhome charging unit. Sadly the lighting strike my house when the motorhome was connected to the grid (230V). The unit chrages the battery and provides 12V to the living area. As I made a couple of tests it looks like the transformer has had it. The fuse on the primary blows even when there is no load on the secondary.

Comment: I just wanted to ask regarding the transformer, but here is a complete issue regarding the motorhome problem : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/382878/mobile-home-battery-charger-transformer

Comment: **3** is the center tap, it's pretty obvious. And yes, it's 26.4V center tapped. I think they may be using the same transformer for 24V battery chargers.